# Nginx Server & Wordpress Weird JS loading

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nginx

I'm uploading a JavaScript file that a freelancer that I hired sends me and when I access this file directly over the url, everything seems fine.

But now when I add one line of code to this file and upload it again, sometimes the changes are not displayed even when I access it again over the url  or the line of code that I added is displayed but some lines of code are missing at the end.

I checked the file that I uploaded several times over different ftp clients and the file is exactly the file that I upload ofc.

The file is part of a Wordpress plugin, I'm running on a Nginx Server, I don't have any kind of caching plugin.

What is going on ?

Comment: It might be possible your browser is caching the javascript files. Try to rename the file or append a querystring in request uri to check if the issue is with the browser side. Or try opening in incognito/private browsing.

Comment: You don't have to have a **wordpress** caching plugin for your browser to cache resources such as js files. F12 > network > if you see that the file is loaded from cache then you know that the browser cached it. Browser caches if it web server tells it to do it.

Comment: I tested that already. I cleared the cache several times and also used the option to disable cache from network tools of google chrome.

Comment: I'm sure that there is no caching browser side.